# parent navbar in html css taking more space than children do

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I'm working on a vuejs project and runing into a problem with the sizing of elements.
Basically my header is composed of a logo and a navbar.

The navbar stretches out the header size.
When inspecting I can see that the links in the navbar have correct size but the navbar takes  more height than the links.

Here's the header code
I don't understand what can mess this up ? what I'm trying to achieve is the same as on the screeshot below, without the two white strips up and down.

```
<header class="site-header">
<div class="wrapper site-header__wrapper">
    <a href="/home" class="logo__wrapper"><img src="../../assets/logo_xsmall.png">
        <p>AOE Builder</p>
    </a>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search a build...">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul class="nav__wrapper">
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="/all-builds">All builds</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="/search">Search</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="/my-account">Account</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
```

as for the css:

```
.site-header {
position: relative;
background-color: #ffffff;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: larger;
}

a:hover{
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: #f8f1e4;
    color: black;
}

.site-header__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

input[type=text] {
    float: right;
    border: none;
    margin-right: 16px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-style: double;
}


.nav__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    list-style-type: none;  
}

.nav__item a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
 }
```

lastly, the global css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: cinzel;
    src: url("../fonts/Cinzel-VariableFont_wght.ttf")
}

#app, body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: cinzel;
}

.content {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    background: url("../bg.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain what that means? `without the two white strips up and down`?

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would help a lot and would greatly increase your chances of having a good response. You can read about how to create it here: stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because `ul` element with links has default top and bottom `margin`. To change this you can reset `margin` for this `ul`:

```
ul.nav__wrapper {
  margin: 0;
}
```

If you just starting this project, a good idea is add some CSS rules to reset default browser behaviors, for example to reset margins some browsers add to `ul` elements by default. Thanks to this you will have more control over CSS styles.